# Java - Constructor with predifined value for inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

In order to make my question clearer, I have simplified names and values, since my code is pretty long and has a lot of variables and methods.
This problem equals my problem exactly:

I'm trying to create a class B that has two constructors, and inherits another class named A.

This is a simplified view of A:

```
public class A {

    int value1;
    List<SpecialItem> itemList;

    public SampleClass(int value1, List<SpecialItem> itemList) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }
```

Now, this is a simplified view of B:

```
public class B {

    public SampleClass(int value1, List<SpecialItem> itemList) {
        super(value1,itemList);
    }

    public SampleClass(int value1) {
        ???
    }
```

Now, the problem is that I want to create a second constructor for B (where the ??? are) that doesn't receive a predefined itemList, but creates its own list. (the object SpecialItem is another class in the same package of the project).

Of course, I am having a problem with defining that constructor, since it does not apply for A's constructor.

My goals are:

1. Do not give the opportunity to initiate an instance of A without a
   given itemList.
2. Have a constructor for B which doesn't give an itemList, but instead I create the one I want and "plant" it in B. For example - that list will have only one object of the type SpecialItem that is created by parameters I give to it.

One thing I though is to create a private/package visibility constructor for A without the itemList and then use that as "super", but I'm not sure whether it is the best solution.

Would love your ideas and feedback,

Thanks.

Comment: `super(value1, new ArrayList<SpecialItem>());`?

Comment: `super(value1, Arrays.asList(new SpecialItem()));`?

Comment: `A` could have a constructor that does not require a `List` (and would initialize the field with an empty list). On the other hand, you should also consider whether you really need to use inheritance, or could you use composition instead.

Comment: I am trying to initiate it by    new ArrayList<SpecialItem>()add,(new SpecialItem(1,2,3)) but It gets it as a boolean and not a list.

Comment: @MickMnemonic can you please elaborate about the composition?
I need to use inheritence since it uses a lot of methods from the class A

Comment: Okay, if there really is an "is-a" relationship between `A` and `B`, inheritance is probably the best way to do this. But you could clarify about what you really would want to do in the second constructor of `B`.

Comment: If you want a pre-filled list use JB Nizet's version.

Comment: The syntax would then be `Arrays.asList(new SpecialItem(1),new SpecialItem(2), new SpecialItem(3))` (it's a varargs method).

Comment: Great, that worked, thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are needing to pass a default list to the constructor of the superclass. I would do it this way:

```
public class B {

    private static final List<SpecialItem> DEFAULT_ITEM_LIST = 
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new SpecialItem()));

    public SampleClass(int value1, List<SpecialItem> itemList) {
        super(value1, itemList);
    }

    public SampleClass(int value1) {
        this(value1, DEFAULT_ITEM_LIST);
    }
}
```

The second constructor of `B` delegates to the first one, which in turn calls the constructor of the superclass `A`. Both the first constructor of `B` and the constructor of `A` require a `List<SpecialItem>` as its second argument. For this, we are using the `DEFAULT_ITEM_LIST`, which has been defined as a `private static final` member in `B`.

Note that I've used `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))` instead of just `Arrays.asList(...)`. This is because the list returned by `Arrays.asList` cannot be structurally modified (elements cannot be added to or removed from it, though they can be replaced by others). The constructor of `ArrayList` that receives another `List` allows to create a common, mutable `List` out of another list.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a problem in creating a constructor without a call to super() in its first line?

Comment: @Mickey You can also call the other constructor in the same class, which in turn calls `super`. This is what I have done.